# Check every character in a .txt file

Tags: c#, arrays, streamreader

I'm working on a game engine, but I have some problems with the tile engine.

I want it so in a text file, I first have 4 rows telling the size of a tile and size of the map, and then the map/array itself, an example:

```
32
32
10
10
0000000000
0000000000
0000000000
0000000000
0000000000
0000000000
0000000000
0000000000
0000000000
0000000000
```

And when the file is loaded(using a streamreader) it runs through the file and checks for special characters - something like:

```
switch(lineReader)
{
    case '#'
    {
        Solid solid = new Solid(Content.Load<Texture2D>("spr_Wall"), new Rectangle(0, 0, tileWidth, tile Height));
    }
}
```

I've been trying in a total of maybe 2 - 3 months with internet searching, but either way I suck at google searching, or just a bad programmer..

Well, eitherway, how would i make something like this possible?

Comment: So where is your problem?

Comment: And what is the lineReader? Is it string? in this case you should also run a nested loop on each character of the string.

Comment: Why don't you use an XML text file?  You can deserialize your object to a strongly typed class.  For example if you have a file which represents your game settings you could have a `GameSettings` class and pass that to an XmlSerializer to read and write to file.  Then it's human-readable and also machine readable.

Comment: Felix.K - My problem is that i don't know how to put together a working code like that.. :/

Comment: you can also use dictionary to implement the different solid definitions

Comment: HTrevor Elliot - How do i use XML? Do you recommend any tutorials?

Answer (score 1):

If the File has the right Format (there is no error checking in my code)

```
private static void Main()
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader("filename"))
        {
            var tileSizeX = Convert.ToInt32(reader.ReadLine());
            var tileSizeY = Convert.ToInt32(reader.ReadLine());
            var mapSizeX = Convert.ToInt32(reader.ReadLine());
            var mapSizeY = Convert.ToInt32(reader.ReadLine());

            char[,] map = new char[mapSizeX, mapSizeY];

            for (var i = 0; i < mapSizeY; i++)
            {
                string line = reader.ReadLine();
                for (int j = 0; j < mapSizeX; j++)
                {
                    map[j, i] = line[j];
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < mapSizeX; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < mapSizeY; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write(map[i, j]);
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: ok, so i added this, and i added 4 rows with one value on each of them, the tile size and map size. (32 32 5 5),

And then i added 5 rows of 5 zeros on each, and when i run the program it generates one rows of zero's. How do i add a variable that i can use in my switch to check for symbols??? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: where there is now Console.Write(map[i, j]); you can use map[i, j] in your switch statement so that you can see the char that is there

Comment: This is the reason why i haven't succeded in months..i don't know how to draw it or when to load and when to add the Draw method.. D:

Is there any code / tutorial whihc can help me?

Comment: Yes, but i tried with C# to decrease the work to see if something works..bad idea i guess :/

Comment: I think this Tutorial is very good: [link](http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/series2d.php)

Comment: Thanks, but what does it have to do with tile engines..?